# Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API 401 Error java

Tags: java, api, cloud, speech-to-text

I'm using Google Cloud Speech-To-Text API in my java program and suddenly google server started to respond 401 error. I haven't made any modifications to the code. I've tried to create a new API_KEY and even create a new google cloud account but the error persists. Anyone knows what may be causing it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you provide a bit of insight into your problem like log files and screenshots of output and a way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply! this is what I'm getting when I make the request: <p>Your client does not have permission to the requested URL
  Invalid key. <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>

The request I'm making is http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?client=chromium&output=json&lang=en-US&key=MY_KEY&maxresults=2